# The connection refused when I used ssh command

Tags: virtualbox, ssh, 16.10

I have a little problem with the `ssh` command. In fact, I'm learning how SSH works, so I'm trying to test it out with two computers.

[image]

Why do I get the error : `ssh: connect to host 10.43.0.106 port 22: Connection refused`? What could I do to fix this problem?

**EDIT :**

It seems that I got the error `ssh: connect to host 10.0.2.15 port 22: No route to host`, when I execute the command `ssh 10.0.2.15` from the other computer.

Comment: could be any number of problems. run ssh with the `-vvv` option and it appears you have a firewall at some point.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I modified the question with changing the picture.

Comment: My guess is either the server is not running or is firewalled . Hard to tell as you are on different subnets (10.43 and 10.128) ? You need to provide more details of your network and I suggest getting ping working as a first step.

Comment: the `ping` command  is already tested; watch the picture

Comment: yes and the ping si not working "100% packet loss" so you have a network problem as your client can not contact the server via either ping or ssh.

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (>100 lines) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is this about the same café hotspot as in your other question? In any case your network gateway prohibits the transmission of this package based on whatever criteria and filters them out but it gives you a nice diagnostic message about that fact in the ICMP response as visible in the `ping` output:

> […] Package filtered

Bottom line: this has nothing to do with SSH and everything to do with IP networking (possibly the network setup of the virtual machine but you didn't share that information with us).